# Commercial .NET CSV Parser/Library

Tags: c#, .net, csv

Our company has pretty much banned us from using open-source libraries in our commercial products due to licensing issues.  We are currently looking for a commercial .NET library that can read and parse CSV files - does anyone have any ideas ?

As far as functionality goes, I really need to be able to read a CSV file into a strongly typed DataTable - with appropriate conversion and flagging of type conversion failures.

Comment: CSVs tend to be really simple. Reading them line-by-line and converting values to object properties is a simple process that shouldn't take more than a day (including debugging).

Comment: Can you provide information what 3rd party parser should support that would *make you happy*? I mean like ie. automatic conversion to  **anonymous objects** or strong type ones etc.

Comment: Great in theory, but in reality there are numerous "gotchas" that can trip you up when reading CSV files (I have no control over the generation of the ones I am reading...) so was looking for someelse to have gone through the pain!

Comment: Agree with Matt. CSVs can be simple, but if you don't have exact control over how the CSVs are generated, there are many ugly things with that, which is why I prefer XML, which has at least a uniform syntax standard...

Comment: A complete ban of open source products? That seems like the people taking the decisions are not well informed. There are many different licences, some more strict than others. Apache license for example is pretty loose. We had the same restriction at our company until we explanined that using some Apache licensed components would probably save 6-12 man-months. So now we can use Apache licensed components ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CSVReader](http://www.csvreader.com) did the trick for us.

Answer (score 6):

.NET has a built-in CSV parser. A real one that follows the RFC to the letter and provides error recovery when some lines are bad but the rest of the file can be parsed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Comment: Thanks - missed that.  Is it VB only ?  I know I can reference it from a c# project if needed...

Comment: It's .NET, you can use it from any language.

Comment: I wish they did not call the library `Microsoft.VisualBasic` because there is no reason whatsoever that a C# app shouldn't use it (as in people in the past have frowned on referencing that library simply because they are coding a C# app - it's all .NET!)

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be well worth studying what the differences are between different open source licenses, so that you can explain to whoever is 'banning' you from using them, what they all mean and what the implications are for your company.

For instance, I would never advocate using a GPL'ed library in one of our closed source programs, but an L-GPL'ed could be made to work. Other licenses are similarly less encumbered.

Also bear in mind that just because a library is published on the web as GPL, quite often, if you email the author(s), you may find that they have other licensing options. For instance I was interested in one GPL library, emailed the author and he said he would be happy to license for closed source projects for $100 per year for support and no runtime cost (that's $100 in total for anyone in our company to use the library on any number products we ship).

This is a damn sight better than $3000 for the development version and $500 per runtime for the commercial library I was also considering. Admittedly the commercial library did much more than the open source library, but we didn't need all that extra functionality at the time.

Answer (score 2):

[FileHelpers v 2.0](http://www.filehelpers.com/)

Comment: -1: "nobody has to know you ripped off the code from them hee.."

Comment: Why use that one instead of .NET's built-in parser?

Answer (score 2):

[Sébastien Lorion's excellent CSV library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) is licensed under the [MIT license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php), so you can do pretty much anything with it so long as you acknowledge the original copyright.

Comment: How is that better than .NET's built-in parser?

Answer (score 1):

How about using built in OleDb in .NET with Jet Engine. It handles different file delimiter type as well. See this article

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UsingJetForImport.aspx

Comment: Aya, I was about to suggest it. There is one problem you should be aware of, there is no 64bit support, so you have to force compiling the product to 32bit (I just found out after installing a new 64bit workstation)

Answer (score 0):

Try [CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) (which I wrote). It has a Ms-PL license. If you can use Microsoft products, you should be able to use this also.